# freeing gpu temporarily in tensorflow or pytorch

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, gpu

I am using tensorflow to train my experiments, and some of them are lengthy and in the middle, I would like to test new implementations, but I need to stop the process, and return to it.
It is not solved with checkpoint saving and loading.
Is there any way to store the GPU condition and the process and restore it again?
I tried kill -STOP, but it does not free up the GPU.

Comment: Why cannot it be solved with saving and loading? Something more about your use case? You could in principle stop your program somewhere, somehow, cast everything to CPU, free GPU manually, run other things, do the same and come back to the previous state (e.g. cast to GPU again) but I don't see why that would be sensible/viable solution tbh.

Comment: Is there anything about the new implementations you would like to test that is specific to GPUs? Why not test it on CPU?

Comment: It is not possible, because I am running about 2000 training with one epoch, and if I want to save and load them again, it overloads the training. I am telling that it is not possible, and I mentioned in the question, so I am interested in a way to release GPU temporarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the `epochs` in `model.fit()` in such a way that it runs for few epochs and end. After that, you can continue the training from where you left using another `model.fit()` by setting the argument `initial_epoch =  history.epoch[-1]`.

**For example -**

Initially you trained for 10 epochs using below,

```
initial_epochs = 10
history = model.fit(train_batches,
                    epochs=initial_epochs,
                    validation_data=validation_batches)
```

Later you can comeback and train for another 10 epochs by using below,

```
fine_tune_epochs = 10
total_epochs =  initial_epochs + fine_tune_epochs

history_fine = model.fit(train_batches,
                         epochs=total_epochs,
                         initial_epoch =  history.epoch[-1],
                         validation_data=validation_batches)
```

You can find a well written example for this [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning). They are doing fine tuning using this procedure.

Also, as suggested by [szymon-maszke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10886420/szymon-maszke), you can use `model.save` to save your model as `model.save` saves all information need for restarting training in your case after loading the model using `load_model`. This works fine with CPU, but I can see issues faced by users while saving, loading and retraining using GPU for this task in Github and Stackoverflow.

Also, you can have look into [train_on_batch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#train_on_batch), `train_on_batch` trains using a single batch only and once. The idea of using train_on_batch is probably to do more things yourself between each batch. Not sure if it will be of much help here.

Meanwhile, you can use the first approach.

Hope this answers you question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @yousef yegane - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.